# Display the AJAX response in Table

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to display the records based on date range.

**Script**

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var info = $("#search").serialize();
    alert(info);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'url',
      data: info,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
        var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
        var trHTML = '';

        $.each(response, function(i, o) {
          trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.patient_name +
            '</td><td>' + o.patient_address +
            '</td></tr>';
        });

        $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table-hover' id='records_table'>
</table>
```

**Controller**

```
public function getsearch(){

    $this->load->model('History_m');
    $fromdate=$this->input->post('dateFrom');
    $todate=$this->input->post('dateTo');

    $date1=date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($fromdate));
    $date2=date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime($todate));

    $result  = $this->History_m->search($date1,$date2);
    echo json_encode($result);     
}
```

**Model**

```
function search($date1,$date2){
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `referral_confirmation_details` WHERE `created_on` >= '".$date1."' AND `created_on` <= '".$date2."'");
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if($query->num_rows()>=1)
        return $query->result();
    }
```

**AJAX Response**

I am getting the output for `alert(response)` as:

```
[
   {
      "ID":"1",
      patient_name":"xyz",
      "patient_email":"xyz@gmail.com",
      "gender":"Male",
      "age":"23",
      "address":"xyz",
      "city":"bangalore",
      "password":"fzf1"
   }
```

I am getting the **error** like "Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0".

Comment: I don't use jQuery but perhaps change `$.each(response,` to `$.each(obj,function(....`

Comment: Is that the exact response, or did you just miss to copy the last `]`?

Comment: @Norsk - You changed the response in the question. Is that because you know that it was wrong or was it because you _guessed_ that it was wrong?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I realised my mistake and tried to cancel/delete my edit but I'm not sure that's possible

Comment: @Norsk No worries, I changed it back. Let's keep it as is until the OP responds to any of the questions/comment.

Comment: It seems like you are passing incorrect variable.. use  $.each(obj, function(i, o) {  insted of  $.each(response, function(i, o) {

Comment: Are you still there? Have any of the comments/answers helped you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(response, function (i, o){
   trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.patient_name +
             '</td><td>' + o.patient_address +
          '</td></tr>';
 });
```

You pass response variable in this each loop you should add obj else you should use parse first and pass in the loop.so you can solve the problem.
and in your json responce there is ] is missing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors inside:

Please change

```
$.each(response, function(i, o) {
  trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.patient_name +
    '</td><td>' + o.patient_address +
    '</td></tr>';
});
```

to

```
$(obj).each(function(i) {
  trHTML += '<tr><td>' + this.patient_name +
    '</td><td>' + this.patient_address +
    '</td></tr>';
});
```

You want to iterate through the parsed JSON object instead of the HTTP response, right? For further reading, please check the documentation of jQuery's `$().each`: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: And to debug your stuff correctly, you should not use the ```alert();```, instead use ```console.log();```. So you hae a proper view on your output inside your console of the browser.

Comment: when i replace response i am getting the error message as Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in Array

Comment: I've updated the answer. If that does not help, please be so kind and upload a version of your code on jsbin, jsfiddle etc.

So the code analyzation will be simplified.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your support.. i have finally got the output for  $.each(response, function (i, o){

Comment: @user5370838 So, would you like to present us your solution and mark the correct answer as what it is?

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the JSON object but the response JSON string.
Try

```
$.each(obj, function (i, o){
  trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.patient_name +
            '</td><td>' + o.patient_address +
            '</td></tr>';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `]` is missing at the end of json

```
[{"ID":"1","patient_name":"xyz","patient_email":"xyz@gmail.com","gender":"Male","
age":"23","address":"xyz","city":"bangalore","password":"fzf1"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to an object. Try below..

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    data: info,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){

        var obj = $.parseJSON(response);   

        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(obj, function (i, o){
        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.patient_name +
                 '</td><td>' + o.patient_address +
              '</td></tr>';
```

});

Comment: it should ba a response while looping

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i finally got the results. I have updated the correct script so that it would be helpful for someone who facing the same issue.

```
   $(document).on("click", "#btnSubmit", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

    var info = $("#search").serialize();
     $.ajax({

type: 'POST',
url: 'url',
data: info,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(response){

    var trHTML = '';
    $.each(response, function (i, o){
   trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.patient_name +
         '</td><td>' + o.patient_address +
      '</td></tr>';
          });
  $('#records_table').append(trHTML);
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```